# InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Int32'

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble presenting the data for a specific table element. The program allows login and logout.
so I have the Personal Trainer class

```
[Table("Personal_trainer")]
    public partial class PersonalTrainer
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("IDProfessor")]
        public int Idprofessor { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column("IDSocio")]
        public int Idsocio { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column("Data_Pedido", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime DataPedido { get; set; }
        [Column("data_Inicio", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }
        [Column("data_fim", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Idprofessor))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Professores.PersonalTrainer))]
        public virtual Professores IdprofessorNavigation { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Idsocio))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Socios.PersonalTrainer))]
        public virtual Socios IdsocioNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have the Socios class

```
public partial class Socios
    {

        public Socios()
        {
            Gerir = new HashSet<Gerir>();
            Mensagem = new HashSet<Mensagem>();
            Participa = new HashSet<Participa>();
            PersonalTrainer = new HashSet<PersonalTrainer>();
            Peso = new HashSet<Peso>();
            PlanosExercicios = new HashSet<PlanosExercicios>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("IDSocio")]
        public int Idsocio { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("email")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("telefone")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("fotografia")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Fotografia { get; set; }
        [Column("sexo")]
        public bool Sexo { get; set; } // true- Feminino
                                       //  false" - Masculino
        [Column("altura")]
        public double Altura { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("nome_utilizador")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string NomeUtilizador { get; set; }
        [Column("peso_inicial")]
        public double PesoInicial { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("_password")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Column("estado")]
        public int Estado { get; set; } // 1 ativo, 0 suspenso 


        //[Column("mensalidade")]
        //public bool Mensalidade { get; set; } //0-nao pago  1-pago

        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Gerir> Gerir { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Mensagem> Mensagem { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Participa> Participa { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalTrainer> PersonalTrainer { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Peso> Peso { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PlanosExercicios> PlanosExercicios { get; set; }


    }
}
```

And I have the teachers class

```
public partial class Professores
    {
        public Professores()
        {
            MapaAulasGrupo = new HashSet<MapaAulasGrupo>();
            Mensagem = new HashSet<Mensagem>();
            PersonalTrainer = new HashSet<PersonalTrainer>();
            Peso = new HashSet<Peso>();
            PlanosExercicios = new HashSet<PlanosExercicios>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("IDProfessor")]
        public int Idprofessor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("nome")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("email")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column("telefone")]
        public int Telefone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("fotografia")]

        public string Fotografia { get; set; }
        [Column("sexo")]
        public bool Sexo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("especialidade")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Especialidade { get; set; }
        [Column("estado")]
        public int Estado { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("_password")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<MapaAulasGrupo> MapaAulasGrupo { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Mensagem> Mensagem { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalTrainer> PersonalTrainer { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Peso> Peso { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PlanosExercicios> PlanosExercicios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So I want that when I log in as a Member I can see the profile of registered teachers through a list and select in detail and see. The problem is that the view appears, but appears only with the name of the fields
The data does not appear.
And I want to see through my profile, logged in as a partner, the profile of my personal Trainer.
In the Socios controller I have this function in order to show me the profile of my personal Trainer.through this method I created a view details.

```
 public IActionResult VerPT(PersonalTrainer personalTrainer, Professores professores, int? id)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId"));


            foreach (var item in _context.Socios)
            {


                if (item.NomeUtilizador == User.Identity.Name)
                {
                    personalTrainer.Idsocio = item.Idsocio;
                    personalTrainer.Idprofessor = professores.Idprofessor;
                    id = personalTrainer.Idprofessor;
                }
            }
            return View(personalTrainer);
        }
```

In the controller teacher I have this function in order to be able to see the profile of the teacher, through this method I created a view details.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> VerProfessor(int? id)
        {

            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var professores = await _context.Professores
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Idprofessor == id);
            if (professores == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View();



        }
```

In the verPT view I have

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.PersonalTrainer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "VerPT";
}

    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 0px;
            background-color: darkgray;
            background-image: url();
            background-image: url();
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>

<div>
    <h4>Personal Trainer</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            Data de inicio :
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataInicio)
        </dd>

        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            Email 
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IdprofessorNavigation.Email)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<div>

    <a asp-action="PerfilSocio">Voltar</a>
</div>
```

In the verprofesssor view I have

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Professores
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "VerProfessor";
}

<style>

    body {
        padding-top: 0px;
        background-color: gray;
        background-image: url();
        background-image: url();
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<br />
<br />

<div style="color:white">


    <dl class="row">
        @*<dt class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fotografia)
            </dt>*@
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            <img src="~/Fotos/ + model.Fotografia " />

        </dd>
        <br />

        <p>Contactos </p>

        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefone)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telefone)
        </dd>

        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sexo)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @if (@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sexo) == "true")
            {
                <p>Feminino</p>
            }
            else
            {
                <p>Masculino</p>
            }
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Especialidade)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Especialidade)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>

<div>

    <a asp-action="ListarProfessores">Voltar < </a>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select e.g. the C language tag instead of the C# one.

Comment: Can you please show me your `VerProfessor` and `VerPT` views?

Comment: as well?
The VerPt function is so that I can see the profile of my personal trainer, and the verprofessor function is so that through a list I can see the details of that teacher
I want to do this when I'm logged in as a Partner, but the fields in the views appear without data

Comment: @rsd_17 Yes that would help out since I need to see what what model are you sending to the `Views` and also how you have structured your model data in your html tags

Comment: That is, do you want to see how VerPT and verprofessor views?

Comment: @rsd_17 Yes, if you could update your question with the required views, that would be great.

Comment: I already changed the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206853/discussion-between-rsd-17-and-rahul-sharma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is obvious: You need to send a `Model` type to your `View` but you are sending an `int` which is `id` in your case. Since you need to show the trainer profile in your View, you would need to change the model type to:

```
WebApplication1.Models.PersonalTrainer
```

in your `View` and

```
return View(personalTrainer)
```

in your `Controller`

Comment: Shama,  hello, I put it as I said and this error appeared:InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.Models.PersonalTrainer', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'WebApplication1.Models.Socios'.

Comment: @rsd_17 Does `_Layout.cshtml` declare a @model type?

Comment: Hello, can you help me with the view this is loading but don't show me the personal trainer data

Comment: @rsd_17 Okay. You would need to generate the personal trainer data on your `Controller` side and then display the required properties for trainer on the view. What problems are you experiencing now?

Comment: So, I want to pass the teacher's id to the view in order to show me his data. Through the Socio profile I want to view the profile of your personal trainer
but the view appears without filling in the data.
And I have a view that shows me the list of teachers, but when I click on a link to see the profile, the view without filling it still appears.

Comment: @rsd_17 In this line `IActionResult VerPT(PersonalTrainer personalTrainer....`, you are sending a model of type `PersonalTrainer` and then using the `Socios` context to gather the data. Therefore send the `Socios` model to the view and then iterate over the `PersonalTrainer` collection.

Comment: Can you explain better I didn't understand

Comment: @rsd_17 Okay, so what you basically need to do is that separate your context classes from your Model. I would suggest you to create a separate view model for you personal trainer data and get that data based on your context class like you are doing currently in the `Controller` method. Also I do not see where you are getting all the data for a personal trainer based on your query.

Comment: So I have a personal trainer class, and I have a teachers and partners class. The teacher can be a partner's personal trainer.
So I would like to show the data of a specific teacher in a view. But the empty view without data appears with only the name of the fields
Why ?

Comment: @rsd_17 Because you are not populating the `personaltrainer` object correctly with the data to be displayed. Can you update your question with the latest code that you are running?

Comment: I appreciate your availability, I have already changed the question