# InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.Models.PersonalTrainer'

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have a program that allows login and logout.
When I join as a Partner I want to select from the list of existing teachers one to be my personal trainer.
This view is accessed through a link in a list of existing teachers.

I created this function in the Teachers controller

```
public IActionResult EscolherPT(PersonalTrainer personalTrainer, Socios socio, Professores professores)
        {

            personalTrainer.DataInicio = DateTime.Now;
            personalTrainer.Idsocio = socio.Idsocio;

            foreach (var item in _context.Socios)
            {
                if (item.NomeUtilizador == User.Identity.Name)
                {
                    personalTrainer.Idsocio = item.Idsocio;
                    personalTrainer.Idprofessor = professores.Idprofessor;

                }
            }
            return View(personalTrainer);
        }
```

And in the view I have

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Professores

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EscolherPt";
}


<style>

    body {
        padding-top: 0px;
        background-color: gray;
        background-image: url();
        background-image: url();
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <h4 style="color : red">Tem a certeza que deseja solicitar este personal trainer ? </h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefone)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telefone)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fotografia)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            <img src="~/Fotos/ + model.Fotografia " />

        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sexo)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @if (@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sexo) == "true")
            {
                <p>Feminino</p>
            }
            else
            {
                <p>Masculino</p>
            }
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Especialidade)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Especialidade)
        </dd>
        @*<dt class = "col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estado)
            </dt>
            <dd class = "col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Estado)
            </dd>
            <dt class = "col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
            </dt>
            <dd class = "col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Password)
            </dd>*@
    </dl>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Solicitar" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Can someone help me fix this error ?

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.Models.PersonalTrainer', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'WebApplication1.Models.Professores'.
```

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946688/invalidoperationexception-the-model-item-passed-into-the-viewdatadictionary-is)?

Comment: And you *still* don't use the correct language tag. This time you have to edit the question yourself.

Comment: @Algum programador I tried to put it as C # and when I press post the # disappears. I removed C #
I am not able to solve this problem in the code.

Comment: If there are multiple tags that could fit your input, then you need to explicitly select the proper tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Int32'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946688/invalidoperationexception-the-model-item-passed-into-the-viewdatadictionary-is)